# Building asp.net core .csproj (VS 2017) on team city

Tags: asp.net-core, teamcity, visual-studio-2017

Is it possible now to build asp.net core projects converted in Visual Studio 2017 to .csproj format on Team City?

The plugin that JetBrains recommends her: [Build, test and deploy .NET Core projects with TeamCity](https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2016/11/teamcity-dotnet-core/) seems to require project.json which is gone in VS 2017.

I expected to get an VS 2017 option in Visual Studio (sln) step after I installed VS 2017 RC but it's not there.

[image]

Comment: @sebastian-belczyk, VS 2017 will be available in TeamCity 10.0.4 which should be released in couple of weeks: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-47785

Comment: @dtretyakov thank you for digging it out, it's really good news for me thanks agian!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dotnet core projects can be build using the pluging ".NET Core Support" from Jetbrains instead of the "Visual studio" build step.

1. Install pluging "[.NET Core Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9190--net-core-support)" from Jetbrains in Team city. (remember to restart team city to load the plugin)
2. Install [.net core sdk](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd) on build agent if this not already has been done. An update to v.1.1.1 is required if you use the new .csproj with Visual Studio 2017 Core projects
3. Setup new .Net core task to build project - set name + relative path to project folder in "Working directory":

[image: .Net core build step definition]

....This works for me :-)

EDIT:
Team city 10.0.5 contains a Visual Studio 2017 build step (maybe also in 10.0.4 as mentioned in the comment to the question). I have not tried it, as I had problems building VS2015 .net core projects with the Visual Studio 2015 build step and everything worked perfectly with the .Net core build step.

EDIT 2:
I now use the "publish" command as it collects all dependencies from the build + .net core dependencies into the output folder (and the team city build artifacts), ready for deployment :-)